# Positioning two rectangles along the inner circumference of a circle with minimal distance between centers

Tags: trigonometry, circles

### The problem

Suppose one seeks to find the two possible locations of (*p'*,*q'*), the center of a rectangle *A'* with dimensions (*w'*,*h'*) located along the inside circumference of circle with radius *r* such that the distance is minimized to the center (*p*,*q*) of another adjacent (non-overlapping) rectangle *A* with dimensions (*w*,*h*) located at a known position along the circumference of the same circle.

Let (*x*,*y*) be the known center of the circle, which cannot be assumed to be (0,0).

Let (*p*,*q*) be the known position of shape A, with width *w* and height *h*.

Let *w'* and *h'* be the width and height, respectively, of *A'*.

Let  be the known angle of the radius along which (*p*,*q*) lies and ' the unknown angle of the radius along which (p',q') lies.

There are two solutions to this problem for a given set of inputs, one where >*'* and one where <*'*. **The goal is to find both solutions for the values of (*p'*,*q'*).**

The following images show two variants of *A'* for a fixed *A* where ∈(/2,) and where *'*>.

In this variant, *w'*>*h'*:

[image: w'>h']

Here, *h'*>*w'*:

[image: h'>w']

The following images show more examples where = and and where '>.

Example with *w'*>*h'*:

[image: w'>h']

And another with *h'*>*w'*:

[image: h'>w']

---

### Application of solution

I'm a hobbyist who makes free digital watch faces, and I'm looking to place multiple icons around the inside edge of a round watch face. One icon will be located at *A*, and I'd like to find the ideal location for another icon to be placed next to it at *A'*.

[image: Example of application of this solution]

---

### How I've attempted to solve this already

I've been working on this problem for quite a while, and I'm having difficulty finding a unified solution given all the different critical points. It seems that it would be trivial to solve this problem between these critical points if the location of these critical points could be determined.

These are the points, as you change , at which *A'* and *A* move from "touching" along one side (e.g. the bottom of A touches the top of *A'*), suddenly touch at just one point, and then swap to touch along different sides (e.g. the left side of *A* touches the right side of *A'*).

As we consider *A* and *A'* rotated around the circle, the locations of  and *'* when *A* and *A'* touch at exactly one point (their corners) seems to be special points in the solution space where we can adopt different strategies for finding (*p'*,*q'*).  To my understanding, there are exactly 4 such points, shown in the diagram below:

[image: all 4 critical points in the solution space, at which A and A' meet at one point]

For example, if it could be determined that for a given , the solution where *'*> has the bottom of *A'* touching the top of *A*, then it would be trivial to go "up" the height of *A'*, *h'*, and find the 2 locations along the circle where a top corner of *A'* could intersect the circumference.

The top right/left corner of *A'* would be located at *q+(h/2)+h'*.  We could then use the equation of the circle, given it's radius, to find these values for the corner of *A'*. This equivalence allows us to find the position of (p',q') for one of the solutions

q'+(h'/2) = q+(h/2)+h'

[image: Diagram showing how we could find the location of the points at which A' could touch the circle]

[image: Showing the placement of A' after using the above method]

Based on my exploration, I generally believe the solution to finding these critical points involves the angle formed between the sides of *A* and *A'*.  For example, consider the following diagram:

[image: Diagram showing the relationship between the two shapes, A and A']

---

### Relevant questions

This question is somewhat related as a follow-up to my prior question:
[Position a rectangle inside a circle along the circumference](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4613192/position-a-rectangle-inside-a-circle-along-the-circumference)

This question is also related to, but not duplicated, by this question:
[Angle between squares at which they just touch along the circumference of a circle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1792470/angle-between-squares-at-which-they-just-touch-along-the-circumference-of-a-circ)

Please note that I'm asking this question in the context of a computer graphics problem, where the y-axis increases from top to bottom (as opposed to the ordinary numerical scheme where the y-axis "points up."

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: The goal is to find both solutions for the values of (p',q').  The length of this question mainly includes the details of my efforts to solve it, which a commenter on a prior question suggested to include.